Entity Framework Core 7/8 JSON Column - use a Dictionary<int, Object>
I saw this post and tried everything in it and still can't get anything to work for me
Entity Framework Core 7 JSON Column - use a Dictionary<int, Object>
{
    "EntityFrameworkEvent": {
        "Entries":[
            {
                "Name": "abc",
                "PrimaryKey": { "Name": "Jim"},
                "Action": "Insert"
            },
             {
                "Name": "jim",
                "PrimaryKey": { "Color": "Brown", "Hair":"Black"},
                "Action": "Insert"
            }
        ]
    },
   "Duration": 177
}

This is just a part of a much larger json but  I am not having problems on anywhere but this area and only on "PrimaryKey"
{
    "EntityFrameworkEvent": {
        "Entries":[
            {
                "Name": "abc",
                "PrimaryKey": { "Name": "Jim"},
                "Action": "Insert"
            }
        ]
    }
}

public class Log 
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public Data {get; set;}
}

public class Data 
{
    public EntityFrameworkEvent EntityFrameworkEvent {get; set;}
    public int Duration {get; set;}
}

public class EntityFrameworkEvent 
{
    public List<Entry> Entries {get; set;}
}

public class Entry 
{
    public string? Name {get; set;}
    public string? Action {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> PrimaryKey {get; set;}
}

modelBuilder.Enity<Log>(b => 
{
    b.OwnsOne(x => x.Data, cb=> 
    {
        cb.ToJson()
        cb.OwnsOne(x => x.EntityFrameworkEvent, ef => 
        {
            ef.ToJson();
            ef.OwnsMany(x => x.Entries);
        })
    })
})

I am trying to use the EF binding for Json and if I remove PrimaryKey then all of it works, but otherwise it does not. Is Dictionary not supported? I tried other stuff but still did not work.
I was hoping to do this way with the new EF features, so I can then later do a search on the "primaryKey" field to find records in my database.

b.OwnsOne(x => is not complete.

That is just a typo, it complies but when it runs it crashes. Usualy something like StartObject is not right, or can't convert it or something and it is all on PrimaryKey. I comment that out and it works.

PrimaryKey translates to:  public class Primarykey {  public string Name { get; set; }   }

PrimaryKey is dynamic, "Name" is just one possibility of infinite possibilities. The next Json record could have "Model" and not have "Name" and the next one could be "Color". So I can't make a class with a concrete property name in it. It is also not limited to just 1 property. PrimaryKey could have 10 columns for all I know. I have updated my example to make that more clear.

The usual "vehicle" for ObjectModel is Collection. You have a collection of strings; not a dictionary. You can "dictionary" once you deserialize.

Can you give an example how this will look like are you saying no changes to my modelBuilder and change "Dictionary<string, string>" to List?
